# How to mock a variable that is created inside a method - Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, moq

```
Class Myclass
{
   public void CalculateShippingCost()
 {
    /// Some line of codes.

     var discount= new Discount();
     discount.GetDiscount();
     
      /// Some other functionality 
  }
}
```

here I want to mock discount.GetDiscount() call as it make a service call .And I don't want to expose this discount object outside this method .

Answer (score 2):

As you've found, having a `new` statement in a method makes it hard to unit test it. The usual thing to do in this case is to inject the dependency into the class like this

As Mark points out in the comments, you can't just mock `Discount` since you can't have 2 classes with the same name. So what you can do is make an interface that defines what `Discount` does. Then your real `Discount` class and your mock can both implement that interface.

In your `MyClass` class you then depend on the interface rather than the class.

```
interface IDiscount 
{
    void GetDiscount();
}

Class Myclass
{
   private readonly IDiscount _discount;
   public Myclass(IDiscount discount) 
   {
      _discount = discount;
   }
   public void CalculateShippingCost()
 {
    /// Some line of codes.
     _discount.GetDiscount();
    
      /// Some other functionality 
  }
}
```

By doing it this way, you can create a mock of the `IDiscount` interface and pass it to `MyClass` when you instantiate it.

If you have a small number of classes, you can do this *dependency injection* by hand. If you have a lot of classes, you can consider using a DI container to handle it for you.

Comment: This can only work if the `GetDiscount` method is `virtual`, which in C# it isn't by default.

Comment: @MarkSeemann thanks, Mark. You're right. I've updated my answer to depend on an interface instead.

Answer (score 0):

> How to mock a variable that is created inside a method?

As far as I know you can't. A variable that is declared inside a method only exists within that method so there is no way to influence/manipulate that variable outside of the method.

That said there are ways to implement what you want while still following dependency injection practices.

Here are the steps I would personally take:

1. Create an interface for `Discount` (if you haven't done so already). Lets call this one `IDiscount`.
2. Create a factory that can produce that `IDiscount`. It's interface could look something like this:

> ```
> public interface IDiscountFactory
> {
>    IDiscount CreateDiscount();
> }
> ```

(apologies, for some reason the Code Sample layout is bricked for me and can't get it to work. Edit: If I comment-block it as well at least it also does the code formatting)

3. Inject this factory into your class store it in a `private readonly` variable and inside your `CalculateShippingCost` method you can call: `var discount = _discountFactory.CreateDiscount();`

This way the actual `Discount` is only used inside your method, but you can still mock the `IDiscountFactory` (and therefor the `IDiscount` it produces)